How to add an offset to the indirectly addressed memory area in Siemens SCL?
I have a VARIANT parameter in my function block written in Siemens SCL (TIA Portal v17). This parameter addresses the pointer to the memory area. Is it possible to add an offset to this pointer using the integer value defined in runtime? Unfortunately, I cannot use the POKE_ functions as I also need to add the offset to the area shared via the VARIANT pointer and then pass it further.

Siemens SCL is quite static, so adding offsets to the memory area addressed via VARIANT or POINTER type is possible usually over the global unoptimized data blocks and their elements, where PEEK functions become available. But actually, the functionality that PEEK/POKE functions implement for data blocks duplicates the functionality of the ANY pointer type from STL. Fortunately, if you declare a variable typed as ANY, and make an assign to it, the PLC runtime will assign to this ANY pointer the exact memory address of the right operand. Then, adding an offset to the ANY pointer could be done like this:
1. Declare the pointer overlaid by structures containing the offset area
      t_p_RawOffsetPtr : Any;
      t_st_OffsetPointer AT t_p_RawOffsetPtr : Struct
         Byte1 : Byte; // Header constant
         Byte2 : Byte; // Data type
         Word2 : Word; // Length
         Word3 : Word; // Data block key
         Dword : DWord;// Offset key
      END_STRUCT;

      t_d_OffsetWord : DWord; // Offset key
      t_st_OffsetWord AT t_d_OffsetWord : Struct
         Byte1 : Byte; // Area key to preserve
         Byte2 : Byte;
         Byte3 : Byte;
         Byte4 : Byte;
      END_STRUCT;
      t_b_OffsetArea : Byte;


2. Render the offset into the pointer
#t_p_RawOffsetPtr := #io_p_InputPointer; // Assign the temporary pointer: ANY or VARIANT
// Byte2 field contains the unit length code and could be used to control reading
#t_st_OffsetPointer.Word2 := #l_w_LENGTH; // Defined using units from Byte2 field
#t_d_OffsetWord := #t_st_OffsetPointer.Dword; // Retrieving offset encoding area
#t_b_OffsetArea := #t_st_OffsetWord.Byte1; // Preserving memory area code
#t_d_OffsetWord := #t_d_OffsetWord AND 16#00FFFFFF; // Setting elder byte to 0
#t_d_OffsetWord := SHR_DWORD(IN := #t_d_OffsetWord, N := 3); // Bitwise address section removal
#t_d_OffsetWord += #l_w_OFFSET; // Adding offset
// Recovery
#t_d_OffsetWord := SHL_DWORD(IN := #t_d_OffsetWord, N := 3); 
#t_st_OffsetWord.Byte1 := #t_b_OffsetArea;
#t_st_OffsetPointer.Dword := #t_d_OffsetWord;

After this reassembling, the ANY pointer may be used as a value for being passed over VARIANT parameter to the function that requires pointing to memory area with runtime-defined length.
